# Как понять содержалось ли это число в массиве?

Tags: c++, if, for

У меня есть 2 массива:

```
int a[1000];
int b[1000];
```

Затем я ввожу значение в элемент массива `a`:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
```

Также я должен сохранить значение `b[i] = a[i]`, если `a[i]` еще ни разу не встречалось до этого...
Как это проверить?

Comment: С помощью сортировки. Отсортируйте массив a и после этого заполните массив b.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но можно код?)

Comment: нет нельзя - это 3 строки кода (при использовании stl), которые вы должны написать, а не все сделать за вас. Что непонятного в том, чтобы отсортировать массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
    int j = 0;
    for(; a[j] != a[i]; j++);
    if(j == i)
        b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]